# PHP - verify if user exist in DB and display the result without reloading the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I want to check if a user exists in DB, and if exist display some error without reload the page (modify a div). Any idea what is wrong in this code? Or any other idea how to do it? Thank you

```
HTML:
<div style="width:510px; height:500px;">
<div class="message">
<div id="alert"></div>
</div>
<form id="signup_form" method="post" action="register.php">
<label class="label">username</label>
<p><input class="signup_form" type="text" name="username"></p>
<label class="label">parola</label>
<p><input class="signup_form" type="text" name="password"></p>
<label class="label">name</label>
<p><input class="signup_form" type="text" name="name"></p>
<label class="label">telefon</label>
<p><input class="signup_form" type="text" name="phone"></p>
<label class="label">email</label>
<p><input class="signup_form" type="text" name="email"></p>

<p><input class="signup_button"  type="submit" value="inregistrare">
</form>

<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

register.php

```
<?php
include "base.php"; 
$usertaken = '<li class="error">username used</li><br />';
$alert = '';
$pass = 0;
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);


 $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details WHERE user = '".$username."'");

 if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 1)
 {
    $pass = 1;
    $alert .="<li>" . $usertaken . "</li>";
 }
 else
 {
    $registerquery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO details (user, pass, name, phone, email) VALUES('".$username."', '".$password."','".$name."','".$phone."', '".$email."')");
    if($registerquery)
    {
        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";    
    }       
 }
 if($pass == 1) {
    echo '<script>$(".message").hide("").show(""); </script>';
    echo "<ul>";
    echo $alert;
    echo "</ul>";
 }
}
        ?>
```

SOLUTION (add this in head and hide .message div)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
var options = { 
target:        '#alert',
beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
success:       showResponse
}; 
$('#signup_form').ajaxForm(options); 
}); 
function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) { 
var queryString = $.param(formData); 
return true; 
} 
function showResponse(responseText, statusText)  {  
} 
$.fn.clearForm = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
if (tag == 'form')
  return $(':input',this).clearForm();
if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
  this.value = '';
else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
  this.checked = false;
else if (tag == 'select')
  this.selectedIndex = -1;
  });
};
</script>
```

Comment: the page is reloaded and then is displayed the error. I what to display the error above the form.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use AJAX to do a dynamic page update.

Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for how to do it with jQuery.

Your current code uses a form submit, which always reloads the page.

Comment: An example using jQuery: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/04/ajax-login-validation-php-jquery.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ajax. Write something like this as a JavaScript:

```
 var xmlHttp;
 function checkUser(user) {
   xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
   if (xmlHttp==null) {
     alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request.");
     return;
   }
   var url = "check.php"; //This is where your dynamic PHP file goes
   url = url + "?u=" + user;
   url = url + "&sid=" + Math.random();
   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = getData;
   xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
   xmlHttp.send(null);
 }
 function getData () {
   if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
     if (xmlHttp.responseText == 1) {
           alert('Username free'); //action if username free
         } else {
           alert('This username is taken'); //action if its not
         }
   }
 }
   function GetXmlHttpObject() {
   var xmlHttp=null;
   try {
    // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   } catch (e) {
     //Internet Explorer
     try {
       xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
     } catch (e) {
       xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
     }
   }
   return xmlHttp;
 }
```

And in your check.php file, just check against your database if the username is taken or not, if not and simply `echo('1')` if its free, else `echo('0')` o whatever you want. that single number will be handled as the `xmlHttp.responseText`. you can also do something fancy instead of the alerts, like an image. also you need to run the check() fumction either when the user is typing, or when the form is submitted, with the username form field as a parameter. Hope this helps.

EDIT: Oh, also I forgot that in the `check.php` file, the `$_GET['u']` variable contains the the entered username. Check that against the database.

Comment: Not sure why there are not any upvotes on this, for someone like me who does not know AngularJS or ReactJS but is great with php. This is a great solution. Are there security flaws in this? And is there a reason random math is attached to the string?

Answer (score 0):

If that's all in a single page, you'll have to structure it like this:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   ... do form retrieval/database stuff here ...
   if (error) {
      $message = 'Something dun gone boom';
   }
}

if ($message != '') {
   echo $message;
}
?>

form stuff goes here
```

Comment: are two pages one with the form and one register.php